# Yii2: How to set bc and bcc in Switfmailer?

Tags: yii2, swiftmailer

Three short questions:

1. How to set swiftmailer sending carbon copy or/and a blind carbon copy of mail?
2. Where could I get information about this? I have read articles about Swiftmailer but didn't find anything about bc and bcc
3. Is my intention supported by swiftmailer, at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to use `->setBcc($email)` and `->setCc($email)` repectively.
2. Refer to the [**`MessageInterface`**](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-mail-messageinterface.html) class to see the available methods,

   See a method below from my `ContactForm` Model which sends an email with `bcc` `cc` and `to`

   ```
       /**
       * @param $email
       */
       private function sendEmail($email)
       {
           return Yii::$app->mailer->compose()
               ->setTo($email)
               ->setBcc($email)
               ->setCc($email)
               ->setFrom([$email => 'Omer Aslam'])
               ->setSubject('some subject')
               ->setTextBody('test text body email')
               ->send();
       }
   ```
3. Yes it is possible

Hope it helps

Comment: Good job. Took ur code to mine. Thx a lot for this. Gave U reputation points:=)

Comment: :) you are welcome bro @tklustig , i appreciate the vote up thankyou.